# Query returning #VALUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

My query:

```
=Query(importrange(B5 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col3 WHERE Col4 = '"&Q145&"'",QUERY(importrange(B5 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col2 WHERE Col3 = '"&Q145&"'", 0))
```

is returning:

> `#VALUE!` Query parameter 3 expects number values`. But W106 is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

I have the cell format set to automatic, I've also tried setting it to plain text. Kind of lost, it works without the second query statement, unfortunately, this query is used on multiple sheets with a different number of columns so this is my attempt and making this query work with both formats.

Comment: W106 is not part or the formula. Please add more details.

Comment: W106 is the result expected from the select Col3 or Col2 if Col4 or Col2 meets the criteria as set forth in &Q145&. I am trying to query a formatted sheet that has 2 different formats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it isn't clear what exactly you are after so try:

```
=QUERY({IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(B5, "Sheet1!A1:G700"), 
 "select Col3 where Col4 = '"&Q145&"'", 0),"");
 IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(B5, "Sheet1!A1:G700"), 
 "select Col2 where Col3 = '"&Q145&"'", 0),"")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

Comment: The second suggestion works, kinda. The cell that contains the formula says query completed with empty output but the correct results are put into the cell below the one containing the formula. I'm confused by the result. I tried removing the ; and put an OR in its place but that gave me an error.

Comment: =Query(importrange(B5 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col3 WHERE Col4 = '"&Q145&"'", 0) or Query(importrange(B5 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"select Col2 WHERE Col3 = '"&Q145&"'", 0)                                                                                
       I think this is the query I need but it gives a formula parse error.

Comment: I got the results I needed using the following query. Thank you to all that helped.   =Query(importrange(B5 ,"Sheet1!A1:G700"),"Select Col2 WHERE Col3 = '"&Q145&"'",OR("Select Col3 WHERE Col4 = '"&Q145&"'", 0))

Comment: Seems I celebrated to soon. The solution I used did not see the or section of the formula. Back to the drawing board for me.

Comment: The updated query you gave me is giving me a formula parse error and I can't seem to find it.  I started playing with a IF query but not having much luck with that. Wish I had more than view permission to the sheets I need the data from.

Comment: fixed... try it now

Comment: Your formula works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!